# Doctrine DBAL prepared query

Tags: php, doctrine, prepared-statement, dbal

I'm usigne PHP doctrine DBAL and what I want to do is a get method like this:

```
function get($attr, $value){
    $conn = DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ? = ?";
    $statement = $conn->executeQuery($sql, array($attrs, $value));
    return $statement->fetchAll();        
}
get("id", 1);
```

but it doesn't work. I wonder if is possible to obtein parametrization of columns as well as values.
Here is the docs I'm using: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#executequery

Comment: your query is just a string, manipulate it manually to insert the col names you want?

Comment: of course i can, but I still want to know why this didn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You cannot dynamically bind column name (and this is not `doctrine`/`symfony` restriction - it's just how DB works). 
The way prepare statement [works](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp):

> Prepared statements basically work like this:
>
> 1. Prepare: An SQL statement template is created and sent to the database. Certain values are left unspecified, called parameters
>      (labeled "?"). Example: INSERT INTO MyGuests VALUES(?, ?, ?)
> 2. The database parses, compiles, and performs query optimization on the SQL statement template, and stores the result without executing it
> 3. Execute: At a later time, the application binds the values to the parameters, and the database executes the statement. The application
>      may execute the statement as many times as it wants with different
>      values

So you cannot do step 2 without knowing which columns are you going to "use".

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION:**
What you want to achieve can be done by preparing `sql` string first, then parse it (prepared statement) and then bind **values**